# Script for Fb Messenger Mass delete Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, console, facebook-messenger

Hello i'm trying to make a script for mass deleting all Facebook Messenger Chats but it's giving me issues.

With messenger opened i look for the classes of the "menu" element of each grid chat element, then the same for the delete element, and then again the same for the confirm element. I do a simple click for each element... but it's not working, maybe it is because the menu has to appear when hovering the row...

can you help me find a solution? I don't want to manually delete thousands of chat

```
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('oajrlxb2 hn33210v qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 j83agx80 p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl l9j0dhe7 abiwlrkh p8dawk7l bp9cbjyn s45kfl79 emlxlaya bkmhp75w spb7xbtv rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 taijpn5t tv7at329 thwo4zme m7msyxje m9osqain');

var delete = document.getElementsByClassName('d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql oi732d6d ik7dh3pa ht8s03o8 a8c37x1j keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d9wwppkn fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v ekzkrbhg oo9gr5id hzawbc8m');

var confirm = document.getElementsByClassName('a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5');

setInterval(function(){
    let i = 0;
    menu[i++].click();
    setInterval(function(){
        let k = 0;
        delete[k++].click();
    },600);
    setInterval(function(){
        let j = 0; 
        confirm[j++].click();
    },700);
},500);
```

Comment: "not working" is quite broad, did you debug your code? (console.log, browser console, ...)

Comment: i add this code in the console... and the page start acting up... like it automatically start clicking random. you can try opening your fb, going to messenger, open the console and paste that code...

Comment: i rather not do that, automating facebook like this might get you blocked on facebook ;)

Comment: either way, you should add some console.log to your code to debug it

Comment: any suggest?  what could i log?

Comment: Did you write the script or did you just find it somewhere? Do you have any idea what it does?

Comment: i edited a script i found... sure i know what it does, it looks for all elements with menu class, and looping through them click to open the menu, then do the same with element delete and then confirm... but somewhere it gets stuck